# Log file of ld linker?

Tags: linker, ld

I have compiled on Linux 64 bit, with success, a test application with fpc (free pascal compiler).

Sadly, when linking, it does not work.

ld begin to work but after 3 minutes there is a message from ld:

> "ld encounter a error. Linking aborted".

How to know what is the problem, is it possible to debug the linking process or do it exist a log file of the operations done by the ld linker ?

Many thanks.

Fre;D

Answer (score 3):

Yep, `ld --verbose` parameter did the trick.

Fre;D